# Django ManyToManyField Foreign Key Design

Tags: django

As part of an Address Book application, I have the following in my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_id= models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, default=1, verbose_name='ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    contact_no = models.ManyToManyField(ContactNumberTypeField, 
                 through='ContactContactNumber', through_fields=('contact_name','contact_type'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ContactNumberTypeField(models.Model):
    contact_number_type=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, default=1, verbose_name='ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_no = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, 
                 through='ContactContactNumber', through_fields=('contact_name','contact_type'))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name             

class ContactContactNumber(models.Model):
    contact_name=models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    contact_type=models.ForeignKey(ContactNumberTypeField)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return contact_number
```

My question is that why is it when I run **makemigrations**, it throws a **ContactNumberTypeField is not defined** error?

### Update

Correct code is as follows

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_id= models.ManyToManyField('ContactNumberTypeField', 
                 through='ContactContactNumber', through_fields=('contact_name','contact_type'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ContactNumberTypeField(models.Model):
    contact_number_type=models.ManyToManyField('Contact', 
                 through='ContactContactNumber', through_fields=('contact_type','contact_name'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name             

class ContactContactNumber(models.Model):
    contact_name=models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    contact_type=models.ForeignKey(ContactNumberTypeField)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return contact_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContactNumberTypeField` is not defined at the time of defining of `Contact` class.  Change `contact_no` field to this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    contact_no = models.ManyToManyField('ContactNumberTypeField', 
                 through='ContactContactNumber',
                 through_fields=('contact_name','contact_type'))
```

Note the quotes around 'ContactNumberTypeField'.

The other error here is the wrong order of field names in `through_fields` attribute of the `ContactNumberTypeField.contact_no` field.  It should be:

```
class ContactNumberTypeField(models.Model):
    ...
    contact_no = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, 
                 through='ContactContactNumber',
                 through_fields=('contact_type','contact_name'))
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) about **field1** and **field2**.

Comment: Hi, now it is throwing me this error  

ERRORS:
contacts.ContactNumberTypeField.contact_no: (fields.E339) 'ContactContactNumber.
contact_name' is not a foreign key to 'ContactNumberTypeField'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'ContactNumberTy
peField': contact_type?
contacts.ContactNumberTypeField.contact_no: (fields.E339) 'ContactContactNumber.
contact_type' is not a foreign key to 'Contact'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Contact': conta
ct_name?

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I have got what is needed to move ahead! Yes, I understand how field1 & field2 are related...where one is the source & one is the target.